# Decouple multiple variable let in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

I have a separate function that applies different gradient based on specified id, this function returns a compose Brush. When I call this function in my boxscore I have to wrap with let since it returns Brush?. This causes Android Studio to tell me the modifier must also be wrapped with the let keyword. How can I decouple this?

gradient function

```
fun appliedGradient(id: ScreenId): Brush? {
        return when (screen.id) {
            12 -> Brush.linearGradient(
                colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.Red),
                start = Offset.Zero,
                end = Offset.Infinite
            )
            14 -> Brush.linearGradient(
                colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.BLUE),
                start = Offset.Zero,
                end = Offset.Infinite
            )
            else -> null
        }
}
```

Function where applied gradient is called

```
@Composable
    fun GetContent(screenID: ScreenID): @Composable () -> Unit = {
        var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface))
        {
            //apply background image here
            appliedGradient(screenID)?.let {
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize().background(it)
            }?.let {
                LazyColumn(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, modifier = it) {
                    //apply items
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wasn't being able to reproduce the problem. [Here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/47ecf21918b4522c76e298797f2de9e3) is code I've tried in an empty project (`TestScreen` called from `setContent`). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Compose, so I'm not positive about this, but I would think you can move the contents of the second `let` block inside the first. When I have a `let` block with more than one line, I prefer to name the parameter for clarity instead of using implicit `it`.

```
@Composable
fun GetContent(screenID: ScreenID): @Composable () -> Unit = {
    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface))
    {
        //apply background image here
        appliedGradient(screenID)?.let { gradient ->
            val modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(gradient)
            LazyColumn(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, modifier = modifier) {
                //apply items
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah - you're chaining a bunch of calls together, which produce a result that the next step in the chain will act on: Gradient -> Modifier -> LazyColumn, each step is using the result of the last. But because ``appliedGradient`` can return null, that means the value being passed through *at each step after that* might be null, so you have to null check each time. By doing a null check and opening a ``let`` block, you know the value passed in isn't null, so you don't need to do any checking inside there. But you actually have to use `let` because you're executing a line of code you can't chain